# Random matrix and spherical spin-glass

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-matrices, gaussian

The Hamiltonian of the p-spherical spin glass model is

$$H_{N,p}(\sigma)=\frac{1}{N^{\frac{p-1}{2}}} \sum_{i_1,...,i_p=1}^N X_{i_1,...,i_p} \sigma_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot \sigma_{i_p}$$
where $\sigma \in \mathbb S^{N-1}(\sqrt{N}).$ The $X_{i_1,...,i_p}$ are random i.i.d. standard centred Gaussians.

In this paper [in eq. (2.10).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1129.pdf) it is claimed that this Hamiltonian is (if $p=2$!) equivalent to the quadratic form of a random GOE-matrix $M$, i.e.

$$\sigma \mapsto \langle M\sigma,\sigma \rangle.$$

However, I do not quite understand how the Hamiltonian can correspond to a symmetric matrix, because the $X_{ij}$ are not symmetric, as they are uncorrelated. So how can I see this property?

My follow-up question is then: Is there a generalization using symmetric multilinear forms for arbitrary p?More precisely, can I have $H_p = \sum_{i_1,...,i_p=1}^N X_{i_1,...,i_p} \sigma_{i_1} \cdot ...\cdot \sigma_{i_p}$ with $X_{i_1,...,i_p}$ being invariant under cyclic permutation of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spherical two-spin model has Hamiltonian
$$H=N^{-1/2}\sum_{i\neq j}X_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j$$
where the $\sigma_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots N$, are continuous spin variables subject to the constraint $\sum_i\sigma_i^2=N$. The matrix $X$ is a symmetric $N\times N$ matrix of independently distributed Gaussian random variables of zero mean and unit variance.
<sub>Any antisymmetric contribution to $X$ drops out of the sum, so we may assume $X$ is symmetric without loss of generality.</sub>

This ensemble of random symmetric matrices is called the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble (GOE). One may therefore immediately conclude that the statistics  ground state of $H$ (the state with the lowest eigenvalue) is given by the distribution of the smallest eigenvalue of GOE, which is the [Tracy-Widom distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution).

Comment: $\sum_{i\neq j}X_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sum_{i<j}(X_{ij}+X_{ji})\sigma_i\sigma_j$, so if we decompose $X$ in a symmetric and antisymmetric part only the symmetric part contributes (the antisymmetric part drops out of this sum); keep in mind that the $\sigma_i$'s are commuting numbers (they are not matrices), so the order does not matter, and any permutation of the indices has no effect on the sum (this also holds for $p>2$).